# File reading in matlab

Tags: matlab, fopen

I'm having troubles with my code in Matlab. I want to get the mean value of all the elements in the second column in a file, but for some reason the code does not include the last line.
My file looks like this:
[image]

And my code looks like this:
[image]

As you might already understand, my code gets the mean value of all numbers except the last one for Italy.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In future, can you copy-paste code in rather than putting screenshots of your editor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should put

```
line=fgetl(fid)
```

to the top in the while loop.

Comment: Given that they already call `fgetl` outside of the loop, if that's the only change made you're introducing another bug.

Comment: Yes, but this will hint the problem. I think it is more important to point out problem than giving the right answer. It is the poster' s responsibility to do it right anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually suggested by Mathworks to not use `feof` with `fgetl` loops, but to instead check whether the output is with `ischar`.  Simply replace `~feof(fid)` with `ischar(line)`.

A side note: `line` is also a MATLAB function, by using it as a variable name you are shadowing the function.  While it is not critical here, you should try to avoid doing this. If you try to use `line` the function or another function which calls `line` while you have a variable `line` in the workspace, you'll likely get an error. This is why you'll see the examples in the help use things like `tline` as variable names instead.